# Get variable value in component from a service?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to grab the id of the returned user in my user-panel component, however whatever I try it returns `undefined`

Service:

```
  public resData: any;
  public username: string;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  authenticationService(username: string, password: string) {
    let basicAuthToken = this.createBasicAuthToken(username, password)
    return this.http.post(`http://localhost:8080/api/users/login`, {username, password},
      { headers: { authorization: basicAuthToken } }).pipe(map((res: any) => {
        this.resData = res;
        this.username = res.username;
        this.registerSuccessfulLogin(basicAuthToken);
      }));
  }
```

In my component I'm just simply trying to print it out

```
handleUpdate(){
    console.log(this.authenticationService.id);
  }
```

Any suggestions lads and lassies?

Comment: you might not call the service method right to get the id, usually in Angular its in constructor (private authenticationService: authenticationService) and then this.authenticationService.authenticationService.subscribe(data => {data.id}) something like that

Answer (score 1):

In this it seems you are not subscribing to the service call you are making
It is always required to subscribe for the http api call to be made to backend
Just add subscribe to the function call in component and it should work